# How can I get the "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" and "Show on Lock screen" permission by default in xiaomi devices?

Tags: android, permissions, background, xiaomi, miui

I spent lots of days finding a solution but didn't get it.
How can i get the "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" and "Show on Lock screen" permission by default without opening other-permission page? I have also tried "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" but it doesn't work. At first, I thought it was not possible programmatically, but I saw some apps over the play store that have this permission granted and if I replace my app package name with that app package name then my app got permission by default.

[image]

please guide me if this permission approves from the play store or possible programmatically.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: MIUI seems to have popular and approved apps (like messenger) on a system level white list to have those permissions auto granted for "best user experience" while other apps are well - out of luck.